# How to access Neo4j on EC2 from Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I set up a Neo4j database on an EC2 instance. I attached a domain name and created a certificate so that I can access the browser version from https://my-domain-name:7473. From the browser, I can create nodes and modify the database.

Now I want to be able to modify this database from Node, but it's not working. This is what I have:

```
const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');
const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://my-domain-name', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'instance-id-password'));
const session = driver.session();

session
    .run(`MATCH (n:User) RETURN n`)
    .then(function (result) {
        result.records.forEach(function (record) {
            console.log(record._fields[0].properties);
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('ERROR WITH NEO4J CALL');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

The error I get is

```
ERROR WITH NEO4J CALL
{ Neo4jError: Connection was closed by server

    at captureStacktrace (C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestingAWSServerlessExtension\test-node-neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\result.js:263:15)
    at new Result (C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestingAWSServerlessExtension\test-node-neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\result.js:68:19)
    at Session._run (C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestingAWSServerlessExtension\test-node-neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\session.js:172:14)
    at Session.run (C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestingAWSServerlessExtension\test-node-neo4j\node_modules\neo4j-driver\lib\session.js:135:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Documents\TestingAWSServerlessExtension\test-node-neo4j\index.js:7:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) code: 'ServiceUnavailable', name: 'Neo4jError' }
```

I know the cypher query works because when I run this same code replacing my-domain-name with localhost, I get the expected output. So I can't access my Neo4j database unless I am hosting it locally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing bolt.tls_level to OPTIONAL and I was able to connect to my database. This might mean that my Javascript code is not creating an encrypted connection to my database which is something I should look into.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is cutting off the connection, this could be a cert security thing (if the cert is not recognized/served for the bolt driver) or a networking issue (some setting on the EC2).

Is the config setting for bolt.ssl_policy set to the same policy that you use for https.ssl_policy? If not, make that change and restart graph and might work.

Are you running node on the same server as the graph? If the bolt listen address is 0.0.0.0 you could always try 'bolt://localhost' instead of my domain to skip some of the (potential) network issues.